# Connection refused - connect(2) , while using fakes3 +paperclip+aws-sdk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, aws-sdk

I am trying to test aws s3 file upload functionality with the help of paperclip gem,I have installed fakes3 gem and ran fakes3 using
fakes3 -r ~/fakes3_root -p 4567;
I am getting Connection refused - connect(2) error while uploading file.
Here is my aws.yml file

```
development:
  bucket: mybucket
  access_key_id: abc
  secret_access_key: pqr
  s3_port: 4568
  s3_host_name: localhost
  s3_endpoint: localhost
  sslEnabled: false
  s3_force_path_style: true
```

Here is my model's part

```
as_attached_file :video,
:storage => :s3,
:path => ":attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

Please Help,
Thanks in advance